# Send Email internally in Swift

Tags: swift, email

I want to send email in Swift internally while crashing or error generations.
How can I send it internally, in Facebook they open the popup and sent the mail.

How do implement in Swift?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can't send emails from iOS directly without the users interaction/permission (look over [MFMailComposeViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/) class). You can use an external services like SendGrid, Mandrill etc.

Comment: Thanks Marius! have Done that way now